# Parameters in URL causing 404 error

Tags: html, url, redirect

I have a single-page website, that uses AJAX. I pass parameters to JavaScript through the URL. But the parameters are causing a 404 error (because the page is not found). How can I solve this? example:

www.mydomain.com/firstname/james/lastname/smith/age/53/profession/engineer
Causing 404 error. I want it to go to index.html

How do I do routing?

I am using jQuery. This is how I modify the URL.

```
function writeUrlToBrowserWindow(){
    var theString = '/ch/' + currentChapter + '/' +
                     't1/'  + text1Info.code + '/' +
                     't2/'  + text2Code + '/' +
                     'a1/'  + audio1Info.code + '/' +
                     'a2/'  + audio2Code ;

    window.history.pushState(null, null, theString );
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you using jquery for instance?

Comment: Looks appropriate routing is missing.

Comment: I have code that parses the URL, yet the page does not load, because the server cannot find it (because of the parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **url rewriting** here.

Since

```
www.mydomain.com/firstname/james/lastname/smith/age/53/profession/engineer
```

will make the server look for an index page like

```
www.mydomain.com/firstname/james/lastname/smith/age/53/profession/engineer/index.html
```

you will get an error since this file and all the parent folders do not exist.

With an `.htaccess` file configured for URL rewriting, you will tell the server to redirect to another URL with parameters in it, for example:

```
www.mydomain.com/index.html?firstname=james&lastname=smith&age=53&profession=engineer
```

and serve the appropriate content.

I guess you will also need the index page to be in PHP for example, to be able to retrieve the URL parameters.

Or you could also build a hash in the URL and retrieve it in JS:

```
www.mydomain.com/index.html/#/firstname/james/lastname/smith/age/53/profession/engineer
```

You can start reading about this [here](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Comment: That does it. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome. You can accept the answer by clicking on the green check under its votes, if you will.

Comment: If I put the hash, I do not need a re-write rule in htaccess, right?

Comment: Where is the green check and the votes? I cannot find it. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed you had never accepted an answer before :-) (go on every question where you had a good answer and do it ^^). The vote counter is the 0 at the left of my answer. Below it is the vote down button, and the check should be under that button. See : http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png